Error deploying User Access Policy
Not able to deploy user access policy. Getting the error:

An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you
contact support: 2002295043-77668 (-408224866)

Changed the status from Active to Design, but still getting the same error. Any suggestion ?

Please use [edit] and show the XML for the UserAccessPolicy in question. Note that all related metadata objects (permission set, Group, etc must exist in the target or be part of the deployment package. Also be sure to use latest version of MDAPI

Salesforce support said, it is a known issue. We cannot deploy UAP when Package license is added in Policy Action.
https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000xBRTu/unable-to-deploy-retrieve-user-access-policy-when-package-license-is-added-in-policy-actions
